# What classes should I use for this structures when mapping C code to Java with JNA?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna, feature-extraction

This is my first question un StackOverflow, I think this is the best community for trying to solve this problem.

I'm developing a Java app related with image processing and I'm trying to use functions of CVIPTools library (which is written in C/C++) using JNA, but its my first time using this method for this purpose.

I'm getting the following error when I try to execute a little test just to check that I'm being able to execute the C function **rst_invariant**:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:497)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:441)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:361)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:265)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.rst_invariant(Unknown Source)
    at aplicacion.Main.main(Main.java:75)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application aplicacion.Main
```

Obviously, the error is related with memory managing, but I have not enough knowledge nor experience with JNA to detect it. I think the problem could be related with a not valid relation between the C data types and the Java classes I'm using, but I'm not sure.

I attach the code of the original C function, structs and the mappings I have tried to do.

Every suggestion for improving the code is welcome. If you need aditional information, let me know
:D

Thank u so much!!!

**rst_invariant.c**

```c
double* rst_invariant(Image* label_image, int r, int c) {
    int**           image;              /* 2-d matrix data pointer */

    int             y,                  /* Índice de fila */
                    x,                  /* Índice de columna */
                    p, q, i, j, label;

    double* ptr;
    double          moment[2][2],       /* zeroth moment and first moment */
                    moment1[4][4],      /* central moment */
                    moment2[4][4];      /* normalization of central moment */

    unsigned int    rows,               /* Número de filas en la imagen */
                    cols;               /* Número de columnas en la imagen */

    rows = getNoOfRows_Image(label_image);
    cols = getNoOfCols_Image(label_image);

    ptr = (double*)malloc(7 * sizeof(double));

    printf("hola\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) ptr[i] = 0.0;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) moment[i][j] = 0.0;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) { 
            moment1[i][j] = 0.0; 
            moment2[i][j] = 0.0; 
        }

    /*
        Compara el valor del píxel de la ubicación (y,x)
        con el valor del umbral. Si es más grande que
        el umbral escribe 255 en la localización, si no escribe 0
    */

    image = (int**)getData_Image(label_image, 0);
    label = image[r][c];

    for (p = 0; p <= 1; p++) {
        for (q = 0; q <= 1; q++) {
            for (y = 1; y < rows; y++) {
                for (x = 1; x < cols; x++) {
                    if (image[y][x] == label) {
                        moment[p][q] = moment[p][q] + pow(x, p) * pow(y, q) * 1;   /* Para imágenes binarias, considera patrones binarios. Donde f(x, y) = 1 or 0, aquí 1 es blanco, 0 es negro */
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (p = 0; p <= 3; p++) {
        for (q = 0; q <= 3; q++) {
            for (y = 1; y < rows; y++) {
                for (x = 1; x < cols; x++) {
                    if (image[y][x] == label) {
                        moment1[p][q] = moment1[p][q] + pow((x - (moment[1][0] / moment[0][0])), p) * pow((y - (moment[0][1] / moment[0][0])), q) * 1;  /* Para imágenes binarias, considera patrones binarios. Donde f(x, y) = 1 or 0, aquí 1 es blanco, 0 es negro */
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (p = 0; p < 4; p++) {
        for (q = 0; q < 4; q++) {
            if ((p + q) == 2 || (p + q) == 3) {
                moment2[p][q] = moment1[p][q] / pow(moment1[0][0], ((p + q) * 0.5) + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    ptr[0] = moment2[2][0] + moment2[0][2];

    ptr[1] = (moment2[2][0] - moment2[0][2]) * (moment2[2][0] - moment2[0][2]) + 4 * (moment2[1][1]) * (moment2[1][1]);

    ptr[2] =
        (moment2[3][0] - 3 * moment2[1][2]) * (moment2[3][0] - 3 * moment2[1][2]) + (3 * moment2[2][1] - moment2[0][3]) * (3 * moment2[2][1] - moment2[0][3]);

    ptr[3] =
        (moment2[3][0] + moment2[1][2]) * (moment2[3][0] + moment2[1][2]) + (moment2[2][1] + moment2[0][3]) * (moment2[2][1] + moment2[0][3]);

    ptr[4] =
        (moment2[3][0] - 3 * moment2[1][2]) * (moment2[3][0] + moment2[1][2]) * ((moment2[3][0] + moment2[1][2]) * (moment2[3][0] + moment2[1][2]) - 3 * (moment2[2][1] + moment2[0][3]) * (moment2[2][1] + moment2[0][3])) + (3 * moment2[2][1] - moment2[0][3]) * (moment2[2][1] + moment2[0][3]) * (3 * (moment2[3][0] + moment2[1][2]) * (moment2[3][0] + moment2[1][2]) - (moment2[2][1] + moment2[0][3]) * (moment2[2][1] + moment2[0][3]));

    ptr[5] =
        (moment2[2][0] - moment2[0][2]) * ((moment2[3][0] + moment2[1][2]) * (moment2[3][0] + moment2[1][2]) - (moment2[2][1] + moment2[0][3]) * (moment2[2][1] + moment2[0][3])) + 4 * (moment2[1][1]) * (moment2[3][0] + moment2[1][2]) * (moment2[2][1] + moment2[0][3]);

    ptr[6] =
        (3 * moment2[2][1] - moment2[0][3]) * (moment2[3][0] + moment2[1][2]) * ((moment2[3][0] + moment2[1][2]) * (moment2[3][0] + moment2[1][2]) - 3 * (moment2[2][1] + moment2[0][3]) * (moment2[2][1] + moment2[0][3])) - (moment2[3][0] - 3 * moment2[1][2]) * (moment2[2][1] + moment2[0][3]) * (3 * (moment2[3][0] + moment2[1][2]) * (moment2[3][0] + moment2[1][2]) - (moment2[2][1] + moment2[0][3]) * (moment2[2][1] + moment2[0][3]));

    return ptr;
}
```

**Image struct**

```c
typedef struct {
    int image_format;
    int color_space;
    int bands;
    MATRIX** image_ptr;
} IMAGE;

#define bandP image_ptr

typedef IMAGE Image;
```

**Matrix struct**

```c
typedef struct {
    int data_type;
    int data_format;
    unsigned int rows;
    unsigned int cols;
    char** rptr;
    char** iptr;
} MATRIX;

typedef MATRIX Matrix;
```

**Image struct mapping in Java**

```java
@Structure.FieldOrder({ "data_type", "color_space", "bands", "image_ptr" })
public class Image extends Structure {
    public int data_type;       // enum se mapea como int
    public int color_space;     // enum se mapea como int
    public int bands;
    public Matrix image_ptr;   // MATRIX **(doble puntero a struct)
    
    public Image() {
        super();
    }
    
    public Image(Matrix image_ptr) {
        super();
        // Valores por defecto, quizás se puedan eliminar
        this.data_type = 0;
        this.color_space = 0;
        this.bands = 0;
        
        this.image_ptr = image_ptr;
    }
```

**Matrix struct mapping in Java**

```java
@FieldOrder({ "data_type", "data_format", "rows", "cols", "rptr", "iptr" })
public class Matrix extends Structure {
    public int data_type;
    public int data_format;
    public int rows;
    public int cols;
    public Pointer rptr;
    public Pointer iptr;

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public Matrix() {
        super();
    }
    
    public Matrix (int imagenMatriz[][], int columnas, int filas) {
        super();
        
        // Valores por defecto, quizás se puedan eliminar
        this.data_type = 0;
        this.data_format = 0;
       
        // Filas y columnas
        this.rows = filas;
        this.cols = columnas;
        
        // Asignación de memoria para la matriz 
        this.rptr = new Memory(this.rows * 8); // Creamos vector de Pointer con tamanho = alto de la imagen (número de filas). Cada puntero ocupa 8 bytes.
        
        for(int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
            Pointer fila = new Memory(this.cols * Integer.BYTES);
            this.rptr.setPointer(i * 8, fila);
                        
            for(int j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
                this.rptr.getPointer(i * 8).setInt(j * Integer.BYTES, imagenMatriz[j][i]); //Comentar y revisar esto, creo que está OK
            }
        }
        
        // Probablemente, eliminable, de momento lo dejamos así
        this.iptr = new Memory(8);
    }
```

**Interface definition in Java**

```java
public interface I_CVIPTools extends Library {
    I_CVIPTools INSTANCE = (I_CVIPTools) Native.load("rst_invariant", I_CVIPTools.class);
    
    public Pointer rst_invariant(Image label_image, int r, int c);
    
}
```

**Tests I'm trying to execute (I'm getting the error in the last line)**

```java
Matrix test_matrix = new Matrix(test.getMatriz(), test.getColumnas(), test.getFilas());
System.out.println("Píxel (702, 242) = " + test_matrix.getPixel(702, 242));
        
Image test_image = new Image(test_matrix);
        
Pointer vector = new Memory(7 * Double.BYTES);
vector = I_CVIPTools.INSTANCE.rst_invariant(test_image, 242, 702);
```

Answer (score 1):

The key point to understand when mapping structures is when they are used by value vs. by reference.

By default, an undecorated structure is `ByReference` when used in a method/function argument and `ByValue` when used inside a structure.  If you need to use it in a way other than the default, you need to specifically use the appropriate interface.

The `Image` structure includes this native element:

```c
MATRIX** image_ptr;
```

In JNA, that's just a pointer, or a `ByReference` structure.  You've incorrectly mapped it as an inline `ByValue` (by default) structure:

```java
public Matrix image_ptr;
```

This is what's causing your current "Invalid memory access" error.  You're populating the `Image` structure with the values from your `Matrix` structure.  But the native code processing the `Image` struct sees the two ints `data_type` and `data_format` and tries to interpret them as a pointer to where the structure data lives. You don't own that memory being pointed at.

I don't see the full `Matrix` mapping in your question, but you'll need to include the `ByReference` tag for one of the levels of indirection.

```java
@Structure.FieldOrder({ "data_type", "data_format", "rows", "cols", "rptr", "iptr" })
public class Matrix extends Structure {
    public static class ByReference implements Structure.ByReference {
    }

    public int data_type;
    public int data_format;
    public int rows;
    public int cols;
    public Pointer rptr;
    public Pointer iptr;
}
```

Further, since there are two indirections you'll need to actually pass a `PointerByReference` to your `Image` structure, so you'll replace the current mapping with:

```java
public PointerByReference image_ptr;
```

To populate that value:

```java
Matrix.ByReference matrix = new Matrix.ByReference();
test_image.image_ptr = new PointerByReference(matrix.getPointer());
```

Comment: Hi Daniel.
Firstable, thanks a lot for your answer, currently, I'm at work. I will analyze it meticulously in few hours. 

To advance work, what else you need for seeing "the full Matrix mapping"? Maybe including all the code of the "Matrix" class? I can include it when I return home.

Comment: Added "Matrix" class attributes in the corresponding part of the code. I'm going to analyze your answer and I will try to fix the error now.

Comment: My question now is: how can I include the values corresponding to data_type, data_format, rows, cols,  rptr and iptr in my new "PointerByReference" matrix? Previously, I was using the "Matrix" class constructor, but I don't know how do I have to proceed now. I have been searching some information and it seems that I have to define a constructor inside of ByReference static class I have defined, but I'm not sure.